# How to apply avoidance to path following with root motion?

Tags: ai, path-finding, unreal, navmesh, collision-avoidance

My Character Blueprint uses Root Motion to control locomotion (taking location and turning it into a direction to move).

However, root motion is not compatible with avoidance pathfinding such as Detour Crowd AI.

How can I obtain a navigable path which contains avoidance information? Avoidance which will navigate the Character around dynamic obstacles such as other Characters.

[image]

Here's something of a solution I've thought of. Constantly ray cast in direct of travel to as far as the Character will be in 1 second (depending on speed).

If it hits something, start checking at 45 degree angles (trying forwards diagonals, sideways, back diagonals, then backwards) for an empty space until it doesn't hit something.